# Can't connect nonlocally after 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.10, kubuntu, internet-connection

I've just upgraded one of my systems from 12.04 to 12.10. Now I can't connect on that system beyond my local network. Connections within the local network seem to work fine, and I can make nonlocal connections from other machines (like the one I'm asking this question from). I suspect that some routing information has been messed up, but I don't know where to look for it. It's not a nameserver problem -- pinging outside sites by their IP addresses doesn't work either.

I have another laptop next to this one, also running Kubuntu 12.10. On the one that can't connect, **arp** produces no output. On the other one, it produces

```
192.168.0.1 ether 00:23:69:fa:ce:ae C wlan0
```

On the working machine, the output of **netstat** starts with some **tcp** entries. On the nonworking one, those entries are absent.

I asked this question on the Ubuntu forum but haven't gotten any answers there.  One further complication: since the troublesome machine has no outside connection, it's extremely difficult to download anything to it.

For what it's worth, "ping 8.8.8.8" produces "connect: Network is unreachable".

Update: after a lot of fiddling, I have my external world back.  I don't know what the key action was, but the first indication of progress was that "ping 8.8.8.8" worked.  At that point I still didn't have a working nameserver, so external URLs didn't work.  But I did this (based on an online post, of course):

sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf

and answered Yes to all prompts.  That did the trick!!

Apparently my problem was unique, or close to it, since I couldn't find any online references to it: local net working, remote net not working, including explicit IP addresses.  So I suppose that if no one else has this problem, no one cares about the solution!!

Comment: Your problem is unfortunately not unique. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1000244.

Answer (score 1):

I was (and am) having a similar problem while connecting to the Internet using my MTS MBlaze (India) dongle which is a ZTE device. I am using Kubuntu 12.10.

A while back I was only able to connect to the device from Network Manager applet, but a ping to any address including 8.8.8.8 resulted in "Network is unreachable". I figured out this could primarily be because of my host not being able to connect to MTS gateway.

`ifconfig` shows something similar to the following:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:180.215.149.123  P-t-P:10.228.10.5  Mask:255.255.255.25
```

I used the `route` command to manually add the gateway address (P-t-P in above ifconfig output) as follows:

```
sudo route add default gw 10.228.10.5
```

And voila, I was able to ping again, even to google.com (as dongle devices auto configure DNS servers as well); there is no need to change `/etc/resolv.conf` at all.

Now I need to figure out how to automate this. Any help most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I know you said that it's not a nameserver problem, but changing the nameserver entry in /etc/resolv.conf from loopback address to 8.8.8.8 did the trick for me.

Comment: Note that editing /etc/resolv.conf by hand is deprecated in Ubuntu 12.04 and later. You should do it the resolvconf way instead.

Comment: Good info, Mahalo.